# Accessing Related Model's not yet mentioned

Tags: cucumber, pickle, factory-bot

I have a User factory that references a Company

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.first_name "John"
  f.last_name "Smith"
  f.password "test01"
  f.password_confirmation {|u| u.password}
  f.email "john.smith@example.com"
  f.association :company, :factory => :company
end

Factory.define :company do |f|
  f.name "My Company"
end
```

The Company has many Users. Now I want Company to have many Clients.
There is no need to mention the company, other than to check that once
the client is created, then it belongs to the company.

```
  Scenario: Creating a client adds them to a user's company
    Given a user "John" has registered with "john.sm...@example.com",
"test01"
    And I login with "john.smith@example.com", "test01"
    And I am on the list of clients
    When I follow "Add New Client"
    When I fill in "Name" with "My Fav Client"
    And I press "Create"
    Then a client should exist with name: "My Fav Client"
    And that client should be in my company's clients # needs the
right syntax
```

The last sentence is my concern. How do I tell Pickle that the user I
am logged in with had a company model associated with it from the
factory, so check that company to see if there is now a client
associated with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Associations in factory_girl are little tricky, maybe callbacks (a brand new feature) will help you? Have a look on http://codeulate.com/2009/11/factory_girl-callbacks/